# Xamarin.Forms Droid project warning about .csproj.filelistabsolute.txt

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.droid

I was wondering how to fix these warnings from my Xamarin.Forms project.  They are only warnings, but we need to clean up our warnings, so this can't be here.

> Could not write lines to file *"obj\Debug\Eagle.Framework.Common.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt"*. The process cannot access the file *'C:\Builds\Eagle.Framework\Framework\Common\Eagle.Framework.Common\obj\Debug\Eagle.Framework.Common.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt'* because it is being used by another process.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I looked at several places on how to fix this, but none of the solutions work (besides turning off parallel building, which isn't an option).  But all these are **errors**.  In my case they are **warnings**.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36190
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56013/upgrade-to-xamarin-4-brings-vs2015-problems

Here is some of the information from my Visual Studio help dialog.

> Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.1
>
> Xamarin 4.4.0.34
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK 7.2.0.7

I also posted this question on the Xamarin forums.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93165/xamarin-forms-droid-project-warning-about-csproj-filelistabsolute-txt/p1?new=1

Comment: have you ever found an answer to this?

Comment: Not yet, it has been put on the back burner at the moment.  I will answer this post when we find a solution.

Comment: FYI, the issue has seemed to have gone away.  I am not experiencing this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for a solution;

I have been seeing this error with VS2017 and for my case the only way to carry on debugging is to delete all the bin and obj folders of the projects and then without building the solution, just running it on the emulator or the device.

As you know, when you hit Run, it builds the project anyway.

Hope it helps you or other people until Xamarin fixes this re-introduced bug. You can see the version details below.
[image]